# Is there any way to retrieve the severity level of the messages from system log in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsyslog

Is there any way to retrieve the severity level of the messages from system log in linux?  I have tried the following after being root:

```
 1.  sudo vim rsyslog.conf
 2.  tried to add following lines of code so that I could send every level 
     to separate files 

  ## ------------------------------------------------------------------ #
  ## All levels in a seperate file
  *.emerg                         -/var/log/log.0_emergency
  *.alert;*.!emerg                -/var/log/log.1_alert
  *.crit;*.!alert                 -/var/log/log.2_critical
  *.err;*.!crit                   -/var/log/log.3_error
  *.warning;*.!err                -/var/log/log.4_warning
  *.notice;*.!warning             -/var/log/log.5_notice
  *.info;*.!notice                -/var/log/log.6_info
  *.debug;*.!info                 -/var/log/log.7_debug

 3.  :wq  to save and quit vim
```

However, this does not get saved. Could someone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not as familiar with the older format (and I've not tested this), but this may do what you're looking for:

```
## ------------------------------------------------------ #
## All levels in a seperate file
*.emerg                         -/var/log/log.0_emergency
& stop

*.alert;*.!emerg                -/var/log/log.1_alert
& stop

*.crit;*.!alert                 -/var/log/log.2_critical
& stop

*.err;*.!crit                   -/var/log/log.3_error
& stop

*.warning;*.!err                -/var/log/log.4_warning
& stop

*.notice;*.!warning             -/var/log/log.5_notice
& stop

*.info;*.!notice                -/var/log/log.6_info
& stop

*.debug;*.!info                 -/var/log/log.7_debug
& stop
```

This would end up being my approach just because I like how precise the "advanced" format is:

```
if ($syslogfacility-text == 'auth') 
    or ($syslogfacility-text == 'authpriv') then {

    action(
        name="auth-log"
        type="omfile"
        file="/var/log/auth.log")

    stop
}

# Keep cron messages in their own dedicated file
if ($syslogfacility-text == 'cron') then {
    action(
        name="cron-log"
        type="omfile"
        file="/var/log/cron.log")

    stop
}
```

Setup as many of those blocks as you need to filter based on facility, severity, programname or any number of other message or system properties.

Docs:

- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/conf_formats.html
- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html
- http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html

*EDIT*: rep is too low to respond to comments (odd design choice), so posting reply here.

Re how to save the file:

> If you are referring to "saving" in the sense of your modifications to
>   the file, make sure that you are modifying the correct file. `sudo
>   nano /etc/rsyslog.conf` and then make your changes. ctrl-x to attempt
>   to quit, answer Y to saving the changes. Run `sudo rsyslogd -N2` to
>   test your configuration and then restart rsyslog via `sudo service
>   rsyslog restart`

Comment: How did you save the rsyslog.conf file? @deoren

Comment: @Gayatri Modified my original answer. The Stack Exchange mobile app is being stubborn and will not let post the full reply here.